# Hue shift string of colors

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

I have a number of hex colors (as part of a theme) in say a shade of green. I want to find equivalent colors in another shade say blue.

I would like to set a color and all the colors should automatically become equivalent to that shade.

**UPDATE**

I believe I have to convert the RGB to HSL and then shift it accordingly (between -180 to 180).

Comment: will you show us your color of code??

Comment: @diEcho I don't really have any code. Imagine you have a string of hex colors and want to find equivalent for another color. Similar to the colorize feature of Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: Okay, I've learnt a little more. I need to be able to modify the hue of all the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from RGB to HSV and for the resulting HSV values just alter the H (hue) value to change the base color.

Comment: Had to write a lot of JS to convert HEX to RGB to HSV and then modify the value of H and reverse the whole process.